# Push media files to a seperate nginx VM with Django in production

Tags: django, nginx

I don't know if I missed information regarding this. But I want to know how to store static files to a different VM. I've read that some recommend doing that to larger sites to seperate the load.

My current setup is that I use one computer engine with nginx, virtualenv, gunicorn etc. I use nginx to display the static files (including the media files) on the same server.

How can I push media files to a seperate nginx server when a user uploads an image? How can I obtain the same url as well?

Answer (score 0):

Let's first explore the options of `static` resources(Javascript, CSS, Images, Fonts etc...)

- You have complete control of where this static content should go during the deployment. Typically these resources will go for compression during the build process to optimize the content size to reduce the bandwidth.
- Deploy the static resource on the different server(VM with ngnix) and configure that URL in the Django `settings.py` with `STATIC_URL`. If you use the cookieless domain, it will save little more bandwidth. Refer the section `Use Cookie-free Domains for Components` in this URL: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html
- You can use the content expiry settings for these resources to cache on the client for the specified duration.
- Some best practices are mentioned in the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

For the `media` resources, you can save the files on the shared volume and run it on the different server same as `static` resources. You can configure that server URL in the Django `settings.py` with `MEDIA_URL`.